# How to Retrieve Env Var in Drush

Tags: drush

Is there a way to retrieve shell variables in Drush? I cannot find anything in Drush API docs. If there is no way, how does one handle environment (dev, staging, testing etc.) configurations? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "in Drush"?

If you are working in a Drush commandfile (e.g. writing your own Drush command), then you can get environment variables via php using the [getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function.

If you are calling Drush from bash, then you can use bash to expand environment variables (e.g. `drush dl --destination=$HOME/.drush`)

If you are wondering what to do because you have set up your web server to define environment variables that you are using in settings.php to bootstrap Drupal, then you cannot read these from Drush or bash, because they are only defined by your webserver.  Try defining equivalent variables in your .bashrc.

Comment: By 'in drush' i mean i have script that is interpreted by drush(i.e#!/usr/bin/env drush) and in this script I am utilizing drush commands. I was hoping there is drush command like Node.js have process.env.VAR_NAME to grab env variables

Comment: Writing Drush commands sound fun. I will look into. The 'getenv' is not working for my zsh setup. I guess i will have to figure that out, so I can use 'getenv'.

Comment: I guess i am not clear about the approach "If you are calling Drush from bash...", is there more info in this like a blog post, etc. Any blog post on handling environments with drush would help.

Comment: You need to be more clear about your question and your environment. If getenv is not working, then it is likely that the environment variable you are trying to check has not been set -- for example, if you set environment variables in the Web Server, then Drush will not see these.  Look for some articles on defining environment variables in zsh, and then set the variables you need in the appropriate configuration file.

Comment: Thanks Greg on feedback for me better presenting question. It helps me get better.

Comment: " Try defining equivalent variables in your .bashrc." was useful